# If $A$ and $B$ have the same degree of nilpotence, do they have the same rank?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, nilpotence

Let $A, B$ be nilpotent $n\times n$ matrices over the field $K$. Is the following correct?

> If $A$ and $B$ has the same degree of nilpotency, then $\operatorname{rank} A = \operatorname{rank} B $

Answer (score 2):

This is not correct.  As a counter-example, consider
$$
A = \pmatrix{0&1\\&0\\&&0\\&&&0}, \quad
B = \pmatrix{0&1\\&0\\&&0&1\\&&&0}
$$
which both have nilpotency degree $2$.

This is true, however, for $n \leq 3$, since nilpotent matrix of the same nilpotency degree are necessarily similar (since they have the same Jordan form).

Comment: Can you detail for $n=3$, please? I don't get why it works for that case.

Comment: Do you know what "Jordan Normal Form" is?

Comment: Yes. I see how to justify that using the invariant factors of the Smith form, but not with Jordan.

Comment: Smith form doesn't help here

Comment: You are right... For that I would need an extra hypothesis, A and B should have the same minimal polynomial. Then I can use the invariant factors...